# Given $v, w, z \in \mathbb{R}$, show this equation as true

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

I am now trying to understand, given $v, w, z \in \mathbb{R^{3}}$, its true that $(v\times w)\times z$=$c_{1}v+c_{2}+c_{3}(v \times w)$. $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3} \in \mathbb{R}$. This is cros product by the way.

So this is a true equation. But I want to know how to show $c_{1}=-w\cdot z, c_{2}=v\cdot z, c_{3}=0$.

I first want to prove $c_{3}=0$, I want to let $v$x$w=n$, make the dot product of n and $c_{1}v+c_{2}+c_{3}(v \times w)$ to prove that $c_{3}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of cross product is $c=a\times b$, is

$c_x=a_yb_z-a_zb_y$

$c_y=a_zb_x-a_xb_z$

$c_z=a_xb_y-a_yb_x$

Now, for your expression, $d=(v\times w)\times z=-z\times (v\times w)$ because the cross product is "anticommutative." By the component wise definition of cross product, $$\begin{split}d_x&=-z_y(v\times w)_z-z_z(v\times w)_y\\&=-z_y(v_xw_y-v_yw_x)+z_z(v_zw_x-v_xw_z)\\&=v_x(-z_yw_y-z_zw_z)+w_x(z_yv_y+z_zv_z)+[v_xz_xw_x-v_xz_xw_x]\\&=-v_x(z_xw_x+z_yw_y+z_zw_z)+w_x(v_xz_x+z_yv_y+z_zv_z)\\&=(z\cdot w)w_x-(z\cdot w)v_x\end{split}$$

Likewise, for the y and z components you get $d_y=(z\cdot v)w_y-(z\cdot w)v_y$ and $d_z=(z\cdot v)w_z-(z\cdot w)v_z$. Putting the components together, you find $d=(z\cdot v)w-(z\cdot w)v$.

Thus $c_1=-z\cdot w, c_2=(z\cdot v)w, c_3=0$.

---

You could also use directly the vector triple product, which says that $a\times (b \times c)=b(a\cdot c)-c(a\cdot b)$, or $(a\times b)\times c=-c\times(a\times b)=-(c\cdot b)a+(c\cdot a)b$